# lambda comparator for `std::set_intersection`

Tags: c++, lambda, comparator, intersection

The following code throw a compilation error

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int i):a(i){}
    int a;
};


int main()
{
  std::vector<A> As;
  As.push_back(A(1));
  As.push_back(A(2));
  As.push_back(A(3));
  As.push_back(A(4));
  As.push_back(A(5));

  std::vector<int> Is = {2,4};
  std::vector<int> Bs = {1,2,3,4,5};

  std::vector<A> intersection;

  std::set_intersection
  (
    As.begin(), As.end(),
    Is.begin(), Is.end(),
    std::back_inserter(intersection),
    [](int const& lhs, A const& rhs)
    {
        return lhs < rhs.a;
    }
  );
}
```

> error: no matching function for call to object of type '(lambda at c.cpp:33:4)' if (__comp(*__first1, *__first2))

I failed to implement a lambda function for the comparator of this `std::set_intersection`. I have also tried to overload the `operator>`, `operator<` and `operator==` in class `A` but it still fail. Can you help me out?

Comment: The order of the types in your comparator should match the order of the types of the input iterators.  In other words, `[](int const& lhs, A const& rhs)` should become `[](A const& lhs, int const& rhs)`.

Comment: Does it work if you reverse the order of `As` and `Is`, meaning `std::set_intersection(Is.begin(), Is.end(), As.begin(), As.end(), ...)`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Its not a typo! If providing the reverse order of arguments you get the reverse error message ;) Tested on g++ (GCC) 8.1.1 20180712 (Red Hat 8.1.1-5) on fedora! See my answer, detailed error messages there!

Comment: @Klaus Good point.  I missed that it needs to call the function both ways.  Vote retracted.

Comment: If the Q winds up getting closed ping me [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and I'll help to get it reopened.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is, that the compare function is called in both directions, once with (A,int) and onces with (int,A). I did not inspect the implementation, maybe it is expected that both types are the same.

As a solution you simply can provide both signatures:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A(int i):a(i){}
        int a;
};

// Helper to get Lambda with multiple signatures in place 
// template deduction guide is a C++17 feature! 
template<class... Ts> struct funcs : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> funcs(Ts...) -> funcs<Ts...>;

// if c++17 is not available, you have to write a functor/function
// with both signatures 

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> As;
    As.push_back(A(1)); 
    As.push_back(A(2));
    As.push_back(A(3));
    As.push_back(A(4));
    As.push_back(A(5));

    std::vector<int> Is = {2,4};
    std::vector<int> Bs = {1,2,3,4,5};

    std::vector<A> intersection;

    std::set_intersection
        (
            As.begin(), As.end(),
            Is.begin(), Is.end(),
            std::back_inserter(intersection),
            funcs{
                [](A const& lhs, int const& rhs)
                {
                    return lhs.a < rhs;
                },
                [](int const& lhs, A const& rhs)
                {
                    return lhs < rhs.a;
                }
            }
        );
}
```

I run this under g++ (GCC) 8.1.1 20180712 (Red Hat 8.1.1-5) on fedora. If I only provide one signature, independent of using int or A first, I got the error :

1)

```
no match for call to '(main()::<lambda(const A&, const int&)>) (int&, A&)'
```

or

2)

```
no match for call to '(main()::<lambda(const int&, const A&)>) (A&, int&)'
```

So it is needed to provide a comp function which accepts both signatures here.

Comment: Note that template deduction guides are a C++17 feature (as is pack expansion in a `using` declaration)

Comment: @AndyG: Thanks! Added a note on it.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Klaus suggestion to use a funktor, here is a working example using a funktor.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int i):a(i){}
    int a;
};

class comparatorsForSetIntersection
{
public:
    bool operator()(int lhs, A rhs) {return lhs + rhs.a;}
    bool operator()(A lhs, int rhs) {return lhs.a + rhs;}
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<A> As;
  As.push_back(A(1));
  As.push_back(A(2));
  As.push_back(A(3));
  As.push_back(A(4));
  As.push_back(A(5));

  std::vector<int> Is = {2,4};
  std::vector<int> Bs = {1,2,3,4,5};

  std::vector<A> intersection;

  comparatorsForSetIntersection comps;
  std::set_intersection
  (
    As.begin(), As.end(),
    Is.begin(), Is.end(),
    std::back_inserter(intersection),
    comps
  );
}
```